# How many downvoted question are enough to incur in a question ban?

Tags: support, asking-questions, post-ban

I've tried to make some search but I couldn't find an answer.

Is it possible to incur in a question ban with only one downvoted question?

Comment: This is intentionally not disclosed. But one downvoted question isn't going to be enough,

Comment: And 2 questions are enough?

Comment: Maybe. Maybe not. I will not answer to more specifics as commented above - giving out too much information will make it easier to game the algorithm.

Comment: @Revious probably not either,  unless they were painfully downvoted. But its all offset by upvoted questions so you can't come up with a hard and fast rule. But the typical q-banned users I see have 3 downvoted questions (around -5) and no upvoted questions.

Comment: @RichardTingle: I got q-banned on Programmer with 1 upvoted question and 2 downvoted.. I gave 50 of my reputation away through a bounty. Maybe this did the difference..?

Comment: If giving a bounty factored into this I would be staggered.  Do you have any other deleted questions (perhaps too old to show up in your deleted recent questions tab)

Comment: @RichardTingle: how can I see? However I got q-banned immediately after losing 50 of rep.. It's ipothizable that for very low rep users the alghoritm is more strict.. I really suspect a bug.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, it is not possible to get into a question ban with only one downvoted question.

The ban is there for people showing **consistently** bad questions (where "bad" stands for - low quality/off-topic).

One can't determine such consistent behavior based on a single question.

Comment: Then.. why I got question banned on Programmers? I've got only two downvoted questions.. http://programmers.stackexchange.com/users/recently-deleted-questions/114829

Comment: @Revious - 4 deleted questions, all of which are **also** considered in the question ban.

Comment: thanks, Why I cannot see them. I see only 3 deleted questions, can you provide me a screen or a link also in a chat? I see the ones who starts with: "Microsoft", "Design", "What". Which is the fourth?

Comment: You only see 3 because we only surface **recent questions**. The [fourth](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/224247/jquery-how-to-refactor-jquery-interaction-with-interface) is older than the threshold. The questions displayed according to the **question** age, not the deletion date, @Revious

Comment: But community deleted questions is contributing towards q-ban? Is this wanted? Can you see if the deletion of that question is previous to my q-ban?

Comment: Why wouldn't they, @Revious? Also - please stop trying to figure out the particulars of the ban. You have asked 5 questions on that site. 4 got deleted, 3 got downvotes. 1 has upvotes. This doesn't reflect well on you.

Comment: because, I think, there is a strong difference between a question which is not answered and a question which is downvoted. But can you see if the deletion of that question is previous to my q-ban?

Comment: I can see and I will not disclose what I see. It doesn't really matter what happened first.

Comment: the fact is that I got q-banned immediately after I gave 50 of my reputation away through a bounty. It's ipothizable that for very low rep users the alghoritm is more strict? @Oded

Comment: Sure, you can hypothesize as much as you want ;) Consider though that high rep users will normally have high rep due to good contributions...

Comment: have a look at my rep on the various site. I'm a good contributor

Comment: As it stands, you have has a bad history on programmers, @Revious. I will see if I can do something about it.

Comment: thanks!!! I would really appreciate. If you can help me at disassociating that questions (look also to the effort I made in writing some of them) I could start to better contribute that section again.

Comment: I disassociated one post - you are now out of the question ban, but still close to it. Please be sure to follow the programmers help center guidelines ;)